# How to handle failure senario for kafka and zookeeper in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

What I have zookeeper setup which is running on server1, server2 and server3 and similarly kafka also running in server1, server2 and server3.

Setup are running in kubernetes.

**Problem statement:**

1. In case one zookeeper setup get down entire setup will get down, because kafka is depended to zookeeper. am i right?
2. If Q1 correct - Is there any way to make setup like if one zookeeper server will get down then kafka should run as it is?
3. How to expose kafka port in kubernetes setup ?
4. what is the recommended way to persist data in kubernetes for production server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fail to see how Zookeeper questions are related to k8s... But you definitely should set affinity rules such that Zookeeper and Kafka are not on the same physical servers or sharing same disks

If one Zookeeper out of three goes down, you'll end up with a split brain event in that no single Zookeeper knows which should be responsible for leadership. This effectively can crash or corrupt Kafka, yes.

To mitigate that risk, you can choose to run 5 Zookeepers, in which case you can lose up to 3 servers to reach the same state. The Definitive Guide book covers these concepts in the first few chapters

Regarding the other questions - NodePorts and PVCs, generally speaking.

Use one of the popular Kafka Operators on Github and you'll not need to think too hard about setting those properties

You still must manually perform Kafka admin tasks in any installation... You can use extra services like Cruise Control if you want to reduce that workload, though

Comment: Correct me if i wrong @cricket_007 -

let say, if will follow your approach 3 kafka server will connect to 3 zookeeper and rest 2 zookeeper server are free.
If one of the zookeeper server goes down, then leadership election should happen immediately or it will take few second to comeback normal state ?
And also what will happen if zookeeper server will come up?

Comment: What do you mean "2 zookeeper server are free"? All 5 are working at once unless you set those two to be followers, in which case, they don't do anything until < 3 are running. Leadership happens almost immeadiately, but changes to the rest of the cluster will take a while.

Comment: My bad.. sorry i was thinking each zookeeper service responsible to handle each kafka.
Ok got it... Best pratice to configure zookeeper - 1, 3, 5, 7 or 9 etc.
So for 3 kafka server minimum 3 zookeeper server required. if we lose out one it may crash.
[But 5 Nodes (recommended): A five-node cluster allows you to take one server out for maintenance or upgrade and still be 
able to take a second unexpected failure, without interrupting your service](https://www.cloudkarafka.com/blog/2018-07-04-cloudkarafka-how-many-zookeepers-in-a-cluster.html)

Comment: Only 1 at a minimum , but that's not fault tolerant, and never more than 7, so actually only 3,5,7. And really only 7 for huge kafka clusters, so 3 or 5 depending on your risk tolerance. Number of Zookeepers has nothing to do with number of brokers

Comment: got it ... Thanks